# Selecting data frame value basing on the vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I select values of a data frame given two vectors storing the row and column? For `mtcars`

```
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
...
```

I tried

```
data.frame(row = c(1, 3, 5),
           col = c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')) |>
 mutate(value = mtcars[row, col])
```

and expected to get

```
  row  col value
1   1  mpg  21.0
2   3  cyl     4
3   5 disp 360.0
```

instead of

```
  row  col value.mpg value.cyl value.disp
1   1  mpg      21.0         6        160
2   3  cyl      22.8         4        108
3   5 disp      18.7         8        360
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### apply family in base R

One way to do it is to use `sapply` to go through all rows in your query data frame, and use the `row` and `col` info of each row to index the `mtcars` dataset.

**EDIT: Credit to @Darren Tsai for providing the `mapply` solution.**

```r
library(dplyr)

data.frame(row = c(1, 3, 5),
                 col = c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')) %>% 
  mutate(value = sapply(1:nrow(.), \(x) mtcars[.[x, 1], .[x, 2]]))
  # or mapply
  mutate(value = mapply(\(x, y) mtcars[x, y], row, col))
```

#### rowwise() from dplyr

Another way of doing it is to use `rowwise()`:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(row = c(1, 3, 5),
           col = c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(value = mtcars[row, col]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

#### Output

```
    row col   value
1     1 mpg      21
2     3 cyl       4
3     5 disp    360
```

Comment: Maybe `mapply()` is more suitable in this case because there are 2 args to be used. I.e. `mutate(value = mapply(\(x, y) mtcars[x, y], row, col))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated my answer according to your comment :)

Comment: Thanks! I like `rowwise()` most as it feels most natural

Comment: @user1 Remember to do `ungroup()` after `rowwise()` if you'll continue to process the resulting dataframe :)

Answer (score 3):

matrix indexing to the rescue. See `?Extract`:

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one column
> for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then selects a single
> element of the array, and the result is a vector.
>
> ...
>
> Indexing via a character matrix with one column per dimensions is also
> supported if the array has dimension names.

So:

```
df <- data.frame(row = c(1, 3, 5),
                 col = c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp'))
## character matrix indexing
cbind(df, value = mtcars[cbind(rownames(mtcars)[df$row], df$col)])
## numeric matrix indexing
cbind(df, value = mtcars[cbind(df$row, match(df$col, colnames(mtcars)))])

## both resulting in:

##  row  col value
##1   1  mpg    21
##2   3  cyl     4
##3   5 disp   360
```

As @Onyambu notes, you can also use `transform`/base R piping if you like:

```
df |> transform(value = mtcars[cbind(rownames(mtcars)[row], col)])
```

...or the *dplyr* piping with `mutate`:

```
df %>% mutate(value = mtcars[cbind(rownames(mtcars)[row], col)])
```

Comment: Almost posted exactly the two. You faster! use `transform`  for base Rwhich is closer to `mutate`, ie `transform(df, value = mtcars[cbind(rownames(mtcars)[row], col)])`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(row = c(1, 3, 5),
           col = c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp')) %>%
  mutate(value = map2_dbl(row, col, ~ mtcars[.x, .y]))
```

**Output**

```
  row  col value
1   1  mpg    21
2   3  cyl     4
3   5 disp   360
```

Comment: `map2()` will lead to a list-column. Using `map2_dbl()` instead to convert it to a vector.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Definitely right. Thanks for catching that! Still trying to get better on adding those nuances, which are obviously important.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `diag` to get the values

```
rows <- c(1, 3, 5)
cols <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp")

data.frame(
  row = rows,
  col = cols,
  value = diag(as.matrix(mtcars[rows, cols]))
)

  row  col value
1   1  mpg    21
2   3  cyl     4
3   5 disp   360
```